# Most recent record, prior to date, by category: optimising

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database called `feeds_up`. It looks like:

```
| feed_url | isup | hasproblems | observed timestamp with tz    | id (pk)|
|----------|------|-------------|-------------------------------|--------|
| http://b.| t    | f           | 2013-02-27 16:34:46.327401+11 | 15235  |
| http://f.| f    | t           | 2013-02-27 16:31:25.415126+11 | 15236  |
```

It has something like 300k rows, growing at ~20 rows every five minutes. I have a query which runs very often (every page load)

```
select distinct on (feed_url) feed_url, isUp, hasProblems
    from feeds_up
    where observed <= '2013-02-27T05:38:00.000Z'
    order by feed_url, observed desc;
```

I put an example time there, that time is parametrized. The explain analyse is on [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/OBbd). It takes about *8s*. Crazy!

There's only about 20 unique values for `feed_url`, so this seems really inefficient. I thought I'd be stupid and try a FOR loop in a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION feedStatusAtDate(theTime timestamp with time zone) RETURNS SETOF feeds_up AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    url feeds_list%rowtype;
BEGIN
FOR url IN SELECT * FROM feeds_list 
LOOP
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM feeds_up
    WHERE observed <= theTime
    AND feed_url = url.feed_url
    ORDER BY observed DESC LIMIT 1;
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

select * from feedStatusAtDate('2013-02-27T05:38:00.000Z');
```

That takes just *307ms*!

Using a FOR loop in SQL rubs me the wrong way, how can I make a nice query—like the first one—that is efficient? Is that possible? Or is this the kind of thing where a FOR loop really is best?

**ETA**

Postgres version: PostgreSQL 9.1.5 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973], 32-bit

Indexes on feeds_up:

```
CREATE INDEX feeds_up_url
  ON feeds_up
  USING btree
  (feed_url COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX feeds_up_url_observed
  ON feeds_up
  USING btree
  (feed_url COLLATE pg_catalog."default", observed DESC);

CREATE INDEX feeds_up_observed
  ON public.feeds_up
  USING btree
  (observed DESC);
```

Comment: Just FYI @Cathy has has tried upping `work_mem` to 20MB with the following result: http://explain.depesz.com/s/UJw (from comments on an answer I've now deleted). The sort no longer spills to disk but the query isn't significantly faster. Creating an index `CREATE INDEX feeds_up_feed_url_observed ON feed_up(feed_url,observed DESC);` also did no good; the index is not used.

Comment: What PostgreSQL version, by the way? `SELECT version()`.

Comment: @CraigRinger 9.1.5, I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "id" is serial and always sequential, you might simplify by finding the MAX(id) for each feed_url in a subquery and then pull in the rest of the data as follows:

```
SELECT fu.feed_url, fu.isup, fu.hasproblems, fu.observed
FROM feeds_up fu
JOIN
(
  SELECT feed_url, max(id)  AS id FROM feeds_up
  WHERE observed <= '2013-03-27T05:38:00.000Z'
  GROUP BY feed_url
) AS q USING (id);
ORDER BY fu.feed_url, fu.observed desc;
```

I did a quick test and this works very efficiently utilizing only an index on "observed".

UPDATE:

To use "observed" instead of "id" (since records may not insert in order) you can modify above query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fu.feed_url) fu.feed_url, fu.isup, fu.hasproblems, fu.observed
FROM feeds_up fu
JOIN
(
  SELECT feed_url, max(observed) as observed FROM feeds_up
  WHERE observed <= '2013-03-27T05:38:00.000Z'
  GROUP BY feed_url
) AS q USING (feed_url, observed)
ORDER BY fu.feed_url, fu.observed desc;
```

On my system this ran in nearly the same time with the one index on "observed". YMMV

Comment: That's just what I was looking for! Less than 100ms with a hot cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about optimizing you should describe what [indexs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createindex.html) you have.

I think the one that is absolutely mandatory an index in "observed"

Another index would be "feed_url, observed"

Finally one in "feed_url", might be useful but I am not so sure if this one would do more warm than good. 
Of course the downside of all these will be performance on insert, but for that I would need to know the problem a little bit better.

Have you considered a **[partition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html)** by "feed_url" (since you say you only have a limited few)? Otherwise "observed" by date (month)?

Comment: I've edited to add the indexes I have. As @CraigRinger says above, I have tried making a combined index, but the query planner didn't use it (Yes, I `vacuum analyze`d).

Comment: I don't think a partition by feed_url would help, since I'm always taking one of each (unless I'm misunderstanding partitioning?). I'm willing to try partitioning by "observed", (I can't find any instructions for an existing table?) although that seems a bit extreme for a table with about 200k rows per month.